# Point Cloud Visualizer point cloud is not visible with Oculus VR headset

Tags: point-clouds, vr

I'm trying to use Oculus VR to view point cloud files (*.las, *.e57, *.ply). I have already installed Point Cloud Visualizer add-on. When I import a point cloud file, I can see it on my screen, but when I try to view the cloud points from Oculus VR I can't see anything.

Is Blender able to handle this task?

Are there other steps or stuff to do?